# How do I add automatic capitalization to my url?

Tags: html, css, url

If I typed `example.com` into the search url I would like it to come out as `Example.com`

I've already seen this done. For example `facebook.com/john` redirects to `facebook.com/John`

How do I make my websites automatically capitalize.

Comment: you'd probably need javascript for that. show us what you tried so far. by the way: urls are usually kept lowercase

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using Css alone, the least you can do with css is using Text-transform.

But this can be achieved using little bit of javascript :

**For All letters capitalization:**

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();">
```

Try this code **for first letter capitalization**:

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+this.value.slice(1);">
```

Comment: It turns `john` to `JOHN` and not `John`

Comment: You want the first letter to be capitalised?

Comment: that is what op asked for, look at his examples.

Comment: @JackSparrow check it out now

Answer (score 0):

try this ;)

```js
function doCapitalFirstChar(e){
      var val = $(e.target).val();
      var firstChar = val.charAt(0) ? val.charAt(0).toUpperCase() : "";
      $(e.target).val(firstChar + val.substr(1, val.length));
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" onkeyup="doCapitalFirstChar(event)">
```